# Rollup imported css in a webcomponent

Tags: javascript, web-component, es6-modules, commonjs, rollup

I am creating simple webcomponent now I want to import css , I found a method using adpotedstylesheet.

Here is how I import it my webcomponet

```
import sheet from './styles/swal.css' assert { type: 'css' };

class Demo extends HTMLElement{

   constructor() {
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(Demo.content.cloneNode(true));
    document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
    this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
   }
}

window.customElements.define("demo-component", Demo);
```

and here is my rollup settup for bundling my component

```
import summary from "rollup-plugin-summary";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import { eslint } from "rollup-plugin-eslint";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import { uglify } from "rollup-plugin-uglify";
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: "index.js",
  output: {
    file: "dist/index.js",
    format: "esm",
  },
  onwarn(warning) {
    if (warning.code !== "THIS_IS_UNDEFINED") {
      console.error(`(!) ${warning.message}`);
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      plugins: [],
      extensions: [".css"],
    }),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    eslint({
      exclude: ["src/styles/**"],
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
    }),
    terser({
      ecma: 2017,
      module: true,
      warnings: true,
      mangle: {
        properties: {
          regex: /^__/,
        },
      },
    }),
    summary(),
    replace({
      "Reflect.decorate": "undefined",
      preventAssignment: true,
      ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"),
    }),
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && uglify(),
  ],
};
```

Now when i run `npm run buil` I get the following error.

[!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:38)`

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ???

Answer (score 1):

Currenly, Rollup doesn't support [**import assertions**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions). There is [open issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3799) for Rollup to address it. There is an experimental Rollup [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-import-assert) that supports this but it seems to have some issues.

Another option you can try is to use [rollup-string-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-string). You can use it to read CSS file as a string and then build your constructible stylesheets and assign it to `adoptedStyleSheets` property as explained [here](https://blog.webf.zone/on-styling-web-components-b74b8c70c492) for Webpack. Following is one example of doing it..

```
// Read SCSS file as a raw CSS text
import styleText from './my-component.css';

const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
sheet.replaceSync(styleText);

// Custom Web component
class FancyComponent1 extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    // Attaching the style sheet to the Shadow DOM of this component
    shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];

    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    `;

  }
}
```

> Side note: With Webpack, you can use `raw-loader`.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that adoptedStyleSheets is currently not supported by Safari on Mac and iOS. But, Rollup might handle this for you - I don't know.

Another solution is to check out:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csshtml-module

This CLI tool can be set up to let you automatically compile CSS/HTML to native JS modules.

I created that CLI tool to tackle this issue. It might not be for everyone - but maybe it resonate with you.